# How to list the size of all files in directory recursively at once

Tags: java, file, recursion

I am trying to list the size of all files in directory similar to linux command du -a all at once recursively except in java. Instead of the file going through each file in the directory checking the size one at a time which takes more time

```
String directory = "
File[] parentfile;
parentfile = listFiles(directory);
for (File f:parentfile){
System.out.println(f.getSize());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no magic in this world

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to go through each file, but you can make it easy using `Files.walk`:

```
Path directory = Path.of("...");
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(directory)) {
    long size = stream.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .mapToLong(p -> {
                try {
                    return Files.size(p);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
            })
            .sum();
}
```

The try-catch inside the `mapToLong` is necessary because `Function` doesn't allow checked exceptions.

Comment: I've actually written a library that allows you to use `.mapToLong(unchecked(Files::size))`. It's available on GitHub.

Comment: I want to be able to get the file in all of the directory along with its name too at the same time this only gets the size